# How to move question with no activity to another SE site?

Tags: support, status-completed, asking-questions, moving-questions

I posted [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/810117/how-does-icloud-keychain-store-unsecured-wifi-hotspot-information) on this site due to its technical scope, but I think it might be more suitable for the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site. How do I move the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think a question would be more appropriate on another Stack Exchange site, and you've read the other site's help center to ensure it's on-topic, you can flag your post for moderator attention and select the "other" reason, then ask for it to be migrated. Note that posts older than 60 days cannot be migrated, even by moderators.

Edit: It appears that you did flag previously. The moderator who responded to your flag left the following response to the flag:

> it's your choice, the question is on topic here, but if you don't get an answer, you can delete and re-ask or we can migrate it

To view responses to your flags, you can go to your user profile, and click the number next to "helpful flags". Yours is [here](https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/48154).

Since you appear to still want this migrated, I'll do the migration for you.

Comment: Already did. No response for a couple of days. How long should I expect to wait?

Comment: @pattern86 see edited response

Comment: Thanks for the info about flag responses. This is the first time I've flagged with an expectation of a response, and I did not understand how that worked. It's a shame that responses to flags don't appear in my inbox. I would have expected to be notified of the response that way. Am I missing some setting that allows inbox notifications for responses to flags?

Comment: @pattern86 unfortunately there's no way to do that. There are various feature requests for putting flag messages in users' inboxes.

Comment: Thanks, again, for the help today.

Comment: @pattern86 no problem!

Comment: Devs can migrate questions *even if they are older than 60 days*. This was done as part of the MSO-MSE split (migrating old SO-specific questions from the old MSO, now MSE, to the *new* MSO). Do mods sometimes ask devs to do such?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I've yet to see a situation outside of the MSE/MSO split that warranted having a dev migrate an old post.